# Azure pipeline Slice that got succedded but no data inserted into sql

Tags: sql, azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I have created an Azure Pipeline with copy activity in data factory, no error while running the Pipeline and it got succeeded and its state is changed to ready.But no data is inserted into SQL table.

Here is the Pipeline I created:

```
{ "name": "Pipeline", "properties": { "description": "Pipeline for Copying Data", "activities": [ { "type": "Copy", "typeProperties": { "source": { "type": "SqlSource", "sqlReaderQuery": select * from ResourceField" }, "sink": { "type": "SqlSink", "writeBatchSize": 0, "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00" } },
"inputs": [ { "name": "InputTable" } ], "outputs": [ { "name": "OutputTable" } ], "policy": { "timeout": "00:15:00", "concurrency": 1, "retry": 3 }, "scheduler": { "frequency": "Hour", "interval": 1 }, "name": "CopyActivity" } ], "start": "2016-12-01T00:00:00Z", "end": "2016-12-31T00:00:00Z } }
```

Comment: Well that sucks - did you have a question?

Comment: yes. Regarding Pipeline

Comment: It got succeeded , it shows even Write Bytes but actually no data is inserted into the SQL table.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't help us help you.  All you've told us is that you wrote a bit of code that doesn't error, but didn't do what you thought it would.  You haven't even shared the code you used.  How can we possibly help?

Comment: {
  "name": "Pipeline",
  "properties": {
    "description": "Pipeline for Copying Data",
    "activities": [
      {
        "type": "Copy",
        "typeProperties": {
          "source": {
            "type": "SqlSource",
            "sqlReaderQuery": select * from ResourceField"
          },
          "sink": {
            "type": "SqlSink",
            "writeBatchSize": 0,
            "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
          }
        },

Comment: "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "InputTable"
          }
        ],
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "OutputTable"
          }
        ],
        "policy": {
          "timeout": "00:15:00",
          "concurrency": 1,
          "retry": 3
        },
        "scheduler": {
          "frequency": "Hour",
          "interval": 1
        },
        "name": "CopyActivity"
      }
  
    ],
    "start": "2016-12-01T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2016-12-31T00:00:00Z
  }
}

Comment: This is my pipeline

Comment: @Siyul it gets succeeded but no data is inserted into the Output Table